# How to find files with specific extensions recursively using the for/in syntax?

Tags: bash, shell, file, for-loop, sh

I would like to do something like this:

```
for file in *.sh; do
  echo "$file"
done
```

But recursively, so something equivalent to this (but this doesn't work):

```
for file in **/*.sh; do
  echo "$file"
done
```

Is there a nice and succinct way of doing this?  I really like the `for x in y` syntax.

Is there a nice way of combining this with the `find` command?  I've seen quite a bit of articles using `find`, but the files where never really looped over in the examples I've found.

Thank you for your time :)

Comment: What do you get with `**/*.sh`? Perhaps you forgot to add the `shopt -s globstar`.

Comment: find , -maxdepth 2 -mindepth 2 -type f

Comment: `globstar` is off by default, since `**` has a defined meaning under POSIX. Deviations from the POSIX standard are typically only used by default when they replace otherwise undefined constructs (like `[[ ... ]]`, array syntax, etc).

Comment: Thanks for the info. Is there a POSIX equivalent to **?